# Using BooleanField to toggle hide html element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to implement a checkbox using Flask that toggles if another field is visible. If I do this in just HTML this works fine, but I am clearly not understanding something in Flask about this.

My HTML and javascript is at the bottom of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}


<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>  
    {% block content %}
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Normal Change Request</h1>
            <h4>Hello, Gavin White</h4>
        </div>

        <form class="hide-test" method="post" role="form">
            <div id="core-dte">
                {{form.coreDate.label}}
                {{form.coreDate}}
            </div>
            <div id="hiding-dte" style="display:block">
                {{form.hideDate.label}}
                {{form.hideDate}}   
            </div>
            <div id="chk-button">{{form.hide.label}}</div>
            <div id="chkHide" onclick='myFunction("chkHide", "hiding-dte")'>{{form.hide}}</div>
            <div>
                {{form.submit}}
            </div>
        </form>
    {% endblock %}

    <script>
        function myFunction(chk, txt) {
            var checkBox = document.getElementById(chk);
            var text = document.getElementById(txt);
            if (checkBox.checked == true){
                text.style.display = "block";
            } else {
               text.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Python:

```
class BaseForm(FlaskForm):
    '''
    '''
    coreDate = DateField('Date:')
    hideDate = DateField('Hide Date:')
    hide = BooleanField('Hide')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    '''
    '''

    baseForm = BaseForm()
    if baseForm.validate_on_submit():
        core_date = baseForm.coreDate.data
        hide_date = baseform.hideDate.data
        hide = baseForm.hide.data

        return '<h1>Success<\h1>'

    else:
        return render_template('hide-test.html', form=baseForm)
```

I have googled and tried a few implementations, but now at the pint where I am rady to pull my hair out and need some help. If there is a way to use python to do this and not javascript that would be great, but just want to get this to work more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this for me.

Solution that I managed to work out was that I was referencing html tags I had placed the checkbox in.

```
<div id="chkHide" onclick='myFunction("chkHide", "hiding-dte")'>{{form.hide}}</div>
```

This worked when allowing me to hide the element, but then for reasons I don't understand it wouldn't reveal the element when clicked again.

Resoluton, I loaded the page and inspected the checkbox element, and found it's id, which was the same as its name "hide" I change the function call to reference this as the checkbox to test.

```
<div id="check" onclick='myFunction("check", "hiding-dte")'>{{form.hide}}</div>
```

This seems really obvious now, but in case someone else encounters a similar issue hope this helps.